# android unzip file, no file extracted

Tags: android, zip

Now I need to download the zip file and extract it to the fixed sdcard file in Android. I can download the file already, but I can't extract the zip file. The problem I was found is that `zipinputstream` is null.
The following code are succeed in java programming, I don't understand why this code cannot works in android.

```
public void getZipFiles(String filename, String destinationname){
        try{
            Log.i("filename",filename);
            Log.i("destinationname",destinationname);
            File d = new File(destinationname);

            if(!d.isDirectory()){
                d.mkdir();
            }


            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            ZipInputStream zipinputstream = null;
            zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(new File(filename)));
            ZipEntry zipentry;

            Log.i("read", ""+zipinputstream.read());
            zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();

            while (zipentry != null){ 
                //for each entry to be extracted
                String entryName = zipentry.getName();
                System.out.println("entryname "+entryName);
                int n;
                FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;

                fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(destinationname+entryName);             

                while ((n = zipinputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1)
                    fileoutputstream.write(buf, 0, n);

                fileoutputstream.close(); 
                zipinputstream.closeEntry();
                zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();

            }//while

            zipinputstream.close();

        }catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("!"+e.toString());
            Log.e("err", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

this is my php download file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if($_GET['f']!=null){
    $file=$_GET['f'];//file name
    $url="http://58.176.4.199/"; //path
/*  $num=date("Ymds");  
    $num =1;*/
    header("Content-type:application");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file); 
    //readfile($url.str_replace("@","",$file)); 
    readfile($file);
    exit(0);
}else{
    echo "No file....";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure you have this in your android minifest .      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: also make sure ur destination and source path,,

Comment: 2 of the path are correct, but still cannot decompress it

Comment: every one, i test my code in java, i discover some quite interesting problem, when i download the file in my server, i can't decompress it.
However, i compress other file and decompress it, it works!!
p.s when i using the winrar to show the zip file inside file, i can see the file, but in my java code it can't see the zip file inside file